# Как правильно конвертировать шрифт?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Скачал веб-ширифт с двумя начертаниями `Regular` и `Bold`. Каждого начертания было всего по три расширения `woff2`, `woff`, `ttf`. Я решил конвертировать шрифты что бы получить больше расширений для лучшей поддержки. Для этого я использовал вот этот инструмент:
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Я загрузил сразу два начертания. Выбрал нужные мне расширения и убрал префикс в `Expert` режиме инструмента.

Мне предоставили архив для скачивания конвертированных шрифтов. Я скачал, там были уже конвертированные шрифты и код для подключения. Но проблема в том, что сервис подумал, что конвертирую два разных шрифта, а не один шрифт с разными начертаниями.

И предоставил такой код:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fira_sansbold';
    src: url('firasansbold.eot');
    src: url('firasansbold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('firasansbold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('firasansbold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('firasansbold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('firasansbold.svg#fira_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'fira_sansregular';
    src: url('firasansregular.eot');
    src: url('firasansregular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('firasansregular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('firasansregular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('firasansregular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('firasansregular.svg#fira_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Глядя на этот код, выходит, что для того что бы сменить начертание мне нужно использовать как-бы два разных шрифта, а не разные начертания.

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

> Скачал веб-ширифт с двумя начертаниями..

Это не верное высказывание. Вы скачали не разные начертания, а разные шрифты. Если вы думаете что жирный шрифт это обычный шрифт + font-weight: 700, то это не так. Вес (читай жирность) шрифту браузер сам дорисовывает на свое усмотрение - максимально приводит его к указанным вами параметрам, другими словами он просто "растягивает" букву, тем самым делая ее как-бы толще. А в дизайнерском шрифте, в данном случае это fira_sansbold - дизайнерами рисуется каждая буква в отдельности, тем самым получается совсем другой шрифт.